# Prove $\sum_k (-1)^k \binom{r-k}{m} \binom{s}{k-n}=(-1)^{r+n} \binom{s-m-1}{r-m-n}$

Tags: combinatorics

I need to prove the following identity

$$\sum\limits_k (-1)^k \binom{r-k}{m} \binom{s}{k-n}=(-1)^{r+n} \binom{s-m-1}{r-m-n}$$

In the book "Concrete mathematics" it is suggested to prove via negating the negating the upper index in Vandermonde's convolution, however I do not understand the next step.

The proof does not have to be based on the suggestion above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are interested in evaluating

$$\sum_k (-1)^k {r-k\choose m} {s\choose k-n}.$$

Observing the second binomial coefficient we see that $k\ge n$ or else
it is not defined. This yields

$$\sum_{k\ge n} (-1)^k  {s\choose k-n} {r-k\choose m}
= \sum_{k\ge 0} (-1)^{k+n}  {s\choose k} {r-n-k\choose m}
\\ = (-1)^n \sum_{k\ge 0} (-1)^k  {s\choose k} [z^m] (1+z)^{r-n-k}
= (-1)^n  [z^m] (1+z)^{r-n}
\sum_{k\ge 0} (-1)^k  {s\choose k} (1+z)^{-k}
\\ = (-1)^n  [z^m] (1+z)^{r-n}
\left(1-\frac{1}{1+z}\right)^s
= (-1)^n [z^m] (1+z)^{r-n} \frac{z^s}{(1+z)^s}
\\ = (-1)^n [z^{m-s}] (1+z)^{r-n-s}.$$

This is (use upper negation)

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
(-1)^n  {r-n-s\choose m-s} =
(-1)^{r+m} {s-m-1\choose r-m-n}.}$$